# How do I get around this corner?

Tags: ittle-dew

I'm attempting to complete the game with Ice and Portal only, and that appears to require solving this puzzle, getting to the door at the south side of the room. However, it seems to be impossible even with all items.

I need to either activate or bypass the left gate, which is controlled by (extinguishing) the fire pit. I can use the three available movable blocks to teleport into the square two left of my current position, but this still leaves me unable to aim at the fire pit. I could teleport to directly north of the fire pit, but that's instant death.

This puzzle seems to require me to “go around a corner”, but I don't know of a way to do that (other than mirrors, which aren't in this puzzle).

Small here-is-the-thing-you-haven't-used hints, please; I'm trying to spoil less than a walkthrough would.

[image]

Comment: You've probably solved it by now (or given up) but if I remember correctly, this hint should help: The portal beam doesn't just work on yourself.

Comment: @GeorgeT I don't see anything in the room to use it on. Things I can aim at are only movable blocks, locked gate-poles, walls, and open doors, and the portal wand doesn't do anything to those.

Comment: Your beams can interact with your beams.

Comment: @GeorgeT Perhaps what I'm missing is there. The only specific interaction that I know of is that beams will bounce off ice on walls and the portal _block_ can be frozen. I tried using two ice panels to make beams hit each other and that didn't seem to do anything.